# how to call a function before every $state.go() in angular using stateProvider

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

The title says it all, but in more details; I want to check if the user is authenticated by checking if cookie is available or not before very `$state.go()` call, is it possible to set it globally and not being forced to do it on every `state.go()` function ?

Comment: You want to hook into the `$stateChangeStart` event

Comment: can it be set globally? @CallumLinington

Comment: You set it at the run point of your application

Comment: You can use a service to define when you want it to start, or use the URL

Comment: I updated the question with some more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can hook into the `$stateChangeStart` event which happens each time a transition is about to start. [Docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#events_$statechangestart)

You would do something like this:

```
app.run(['$state', '$rootScope', function ($state, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        // calling event.preventDefault() will prevent the transition, so this is used
        // when you want to stop certain transitions.
    }
});
```

Now there are two options for changing whether you want to prevent a route.

You can use the `toState` and `fromState` to look up in a routing dictionary.

You can use a `service` or `factory` to change whether you can or not.

So if you create a factory, **this is an example, it gives you the concept**:

```
app.factory('routingLogic', function () {
   var singletonShouldRoute = true;
   var service = {
       canRoute: canRoute,
       setCanRoute: setCanRoute
   };
   return service;

   function setCanRoute(shouldRoute) {
      singletonShouldRoute = shouldRoute
   }

   function canRoute() {
      return singletonShouldRoute ;
   }
}

app.controller('somePage', ['routingLogic', '$state', function (routingLogic, $state) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.shouldRoute = false;

    vm.changeShouldRoute = function () {
        routingLogic.setCanRoute(vm.shouldRoute);
    } 

    vm.goNextPage = function () {
        $state.go('some page');
    }
});

app.run(['$state', '$rootScope', 'routingLogic', function ($state, $rootScope, routingLogic) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        // calling event.preventDefault() will prevent the transition, so this is used
        // when you want to stop certain transitions.

        if (!routingLogic.canRoute()) { event.preventDefault(); }
    }
});
```

However, you can switch out the `canRoute` with a dictionary:

```
app.factory('routingLogic', function () {
   var allowedRoutes = {
      "thisroute": true,
      "thatroute": true
   }

   var service = {
       canRoute: canRoute,
       setCanRoute: setCanRoute
   };
   return service;

   // you can pull this out to provider level if you want it in the config stage
   function setCanRoute(routeName) {
       allowedRoutes[routeName] = true;
   }

   function canRoute(routeName) {
      return allowedRoutes[routeName] || false;
   }
}

app.run(['$state', '$rootScope', 'routingLogic', function ($state, $rootScope, routingLogic) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        // calling event.preventDefault() will prevent the transition, so this is used
        // when you want to stop certain transitions.

        if (!routingLogic.canRoute(toState)) { event.preventDefault(); }
    }
});
```

You can go one step further with that if you want to only allow certain route paths to be take. So you can transition from `WizardStep1` to `WizardStep2` but not to `WizardStep3`:

```
app.factory('routingLogic', function () {
   var allowedRoutes = {
      "thisroute": ["thatroute", "theOtherRoute"],
      "thatroute": ["home"]
   }

   var service = {
       canRoute: canRoute,
       setCanRoute: setCanRoute
   };
   return service;

   // you can pull this out to provider level if you want it in the config stage
   function setCanRoute(routeName) {
       allowedRoutes[routeName] = true;
   }

   function canRoute(fromRoute, toRoute) {
      var allowedTo = allowedRoutes[fromRoute] || [];

      return allowedTo.some(function (allowedRoute) { return allowedRoute === toRoute; });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use '$stateChangeStart'

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state, Auth) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
        if (!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('login', {
                next: newUrl.name
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Or you can user http interceptors for API calls

```
.factory('authInterceptor', ['$q', '$cookieStore', '$location', function($q, $cookieStore, $location) {
    return {
        // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
        responseError: function(response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                $location.path('/login');
                // remove any stale tokens
                $cookieStore.remove('token');
            }
        }
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, you have a main module

```
angular
    .module('app.core')
    .run(appRun);
```

You can add to `appRun` function handler of state changing

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(
        evt, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams
    ) {
        ...Do your stuff here...
    });
```